# Adding animation to a shuffle result

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have the following code that shuffles a selection I have in my database. Rather than having the results display all at one, I want to display a result one at a time with a delay between the results.

ie:

If I have 10 items in my database, I want one item to display, then a 3 second delay, then the second item to display, then a 3 second result, all the way until the last item (#10). Then possibly some sort of animation to it, like flying into the screen or the look of an item coming from a bag or something. (think picking a numbered order from 10 out of a bag).

How could I do this?

Here is how I shuffle the db results.

```
<form method="post">
<?php   
    foreach ($array as $result) {
        $shuffle_firstname = htmlentities($result['firstname']);
        $shuffle_lastname = htmlentities($result['lastname']);
        $shuffle_id = htmlentities($result['id']);
        $shuffle_username = htmlentities($result['username']);
        $shuffle_email = htmlentities($result['email']);
?>
        <div class="shuffle_results"><?php echo $shuffle_firstname . ' ' . $shuffle_lastname; ?></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_firstname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_lastname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_username; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_email; ?>">
    <?php
    }
?>  
         <input type="submit" value="Finalize Draft Order" name="insert">
    </form>
```

Comment: what you need is setIntervel, $.animate(), and a for loop.

Comment: Do you know of any good articles or tutorials?